# Slicing based on dates Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, date, pandas

I have a large dataframe with dates, store number, units sold, and rain precipitation totals. It looks like this...

```
  date        store_nbr      units            preciptotal
  2014-10-11       1          0                0.00
  2014-10-12       1          0                0.01
  2014-10-13       1          2                0.00
  2014-10-14       1          1                2.13
  2014-10-15       1          0                0.00
  2014-10-16       1          0                0.87
  2014-10-17       1          3                0.01
  2014-10-18       1          0                0.40
```

I want to select a three day window around any date that has a precipitation total greater than 1. For this small example, I would want get back the first 7 rows, the 3 days before `2014-10-14`, the three days after `2014-10-14`, and `2014-10-14` because it has a preciptotal greater than 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a specific value you can do this:

```
In [84]:

idx = df[df['preciptotal'] > 1].index[0]
df.iloc[idx-3: idx+4]
Out[84]:
        date  store_nbr  units  preciptotal
0 2014-10-11          1      0         0.00
1 2014-10-12          1      0         0.01
2 2014-10-13          1      2         0.00
3 2014-10-14          1      1         2.13
4 2014-10-15          1      0         0.00
5 2014-10-16          1      0         0.87
6 2014-10-17          1      3         0.01
```

For the more general case you can get an array of indices where the condition is met

```
idx_vals = df[df['preciptotal'] > 1].index
```

then you can generate slices or iterate over the array values:

```
for idx in idx_values:
    df.iloc[idx-3: idx+4]
```

This assumes your index is a 0 based int64 index which your sample is

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways you could build the selection mask without looping over the index values:

You could find the rows where `preciptotal` is greater than 1:

```
mask = (df['preciptotal'] > 1)
```

and then use `scipy.ndimage.binary_dilation` to expand the mask to a 7-day window:

```
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
import pandas as pd

df = df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s+')

mask = (df['preciptotal'] > 1)
mask = ndimage.binary_dilation(mask, iterations=3)

df.loc[mask]
```

yields

```
         date  store_nbr  units  preciptotal
0  2014-10-11          1      0         0.00
1  2014-10-12          1      0         0.01
2  2014-10-13          1      2         0.00
3  2014-10-14          1      1         2.13
4  2014-10-15          1      0         0.00
5  2014-10-16          1      0         0.87
6  2014-10-17          1      3         0.01
```

---

Or, using NumPy (but without the `scipy` dependency), you could use `mask.shift` with `np.logical_and.reduce`:

```
mask = (df['preciptotal'] > 1)
mask = ~np.logical_and.reduce([(~mask).shift(i) for i in range(-3, 4)]).astype(bool)
# array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```